# Как добраться до значения итератора?

Tags: c++, классы, stl, итераторы

Нужно написать итератор для моего класса `FlashList`:

```
class FlashList
{
    friend class FlashIterator;

private:
    vector<Flashka> _list;
};
```

Итератор выглядит так:

```
class FlashIterator
{
public:
    FlashIterator(FlashList list)
    {
        _It = list._list.begin();
    }

    ~FlashIterator() {}

    FlashIterator operator ++ ()
    {
        vector<Flashka>::iterator t = ++_It;
        _It = t;
    }

    Flashka operator * ()
    {
        Flashka t = *_It;
        return t;
    }

    bool operator == (FlashIterator& other)
    {
        return (_It == other._It);
    }

    bool operator != (FlashIterator& other)
    {
        return (_It != other._It);
    }

    FlashIterator operator = (FlashIterator& other)
    {
        if (*this == other)
            return *this;

        _It = other._It;
        return *this;
    }

    FlashIterator operator = (vector<Flashka>::iterator& i)
    {
        _It = i;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    vector<Flashka>::iterator _It;
};
```

В гугл-тестах пытаюсь использовать добраться до значения итератора через звездочку, но вылетает ошибка

```
TEST(Iterator, operator_)
{
    Flashka a("Bureau", "A", 32, 56, "21.11.2017");
    Flashka b("Colt", "C", 64, 48, "01.11.2017");

    vector<Flashka> v1;
    v1.push_back(a);
    v1.push_back(b);

    FlashList list(v1);
    FlashIterator i(list);

    ASSERT_TRUE(a == *i);

    ASSERT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы тут копию передаете:

```
FlashIterator(FlashList list)
{
    _It = list._list.begin();
}
```

Попробуйте так сделать:

```
FlashIterator(FlashList & list)
{
    _It = list._list.begin();
}
```

А то потом эта копия `list` удалится и нечего будет разыменовывать и будет ошибка.